# Closure block WILL NOT execute for User notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

This was working on another smaller project, but I cannot get it to work on a large one... The problem is that the completion handler is not even entering the statement as seen below

```
    func checknots()
{
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getNotificationSettings {(settings) in
        print("in heree")
        self.alertNotificationokay = false
        if settings.alertSetting == .enabled
        {
            self.alertNotificationokay = true
        }

    }
}
```

It will not go into the conditional block of center.getNotificationSettings and instead it skips it. When i try debugging it just skips past it and doesn't even go inside the statement where (settings) is. The statement inside doesn't get printed thus, it is stepping over the block statement.

This will execute when I put it in my viewDidLoad, but when i try calling it from a notification, it will not call for some reason....

Comment: Can you verify that center is not nil when calling getNotificationSetting?

Comment: @ghostatron where would I check for this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line with "center.getNotificationSettings..." and then look in the bottom window to check if center was assigned a value, or if it is still nil.  If it isn't nil, make sure it looks valid to you.

Comment: Also, when you say "skips it", do you mean when you are stepping through the debugger it "skips" past it?  If it's async, then that would be expected behavior.  Do you never see your print out of "in heree"?

Comment: @ghostatron yes, the debugger is stepping over that block statement. I do not see the statement "in here" in my command line

Comment: @ghostatron I just went through debugging and the center variable did not register as nil... What were you saying about async?

Comment: I meant that "getNotificationSettings" is probably async, meaning checknots won't block/wait for it to finish before moving on...that chunk of code inside the completion handler won't get called until getNotificationSettings is done.  So if you are stepping through the debugger, it won't step through that.  You CAN put a breakpoint inside it though.

Comment: @ghostatron I figured that this was the problem so I just called it in the viewDidLoad function, but I would like to come up with a solution to this problem. I saw in my debugger that it was entering another thread when it entered this block statement. Do you know a solution to this?